# pyinstaller build with pytorch doesn't execute due to module error

Tags: python, build, pytorch, pyinstaller

I wanted to make a executable from a project.
It uses differents modules, such as torch pygame or numpy.
The build compile without error but when I launch it, it outputs:

```
[13764] WARNING: file already exists but should not: C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI137642\torch\_C.cp39-win_amd64.pyd
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.7)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_interface.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "torch\__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
OSError: [WinError 126] specified module not found. Error loading "C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI137642\torch\lib\caffe2_detectron_ops_gpu.dll" or one of its dependencies.
[13556] Failed to execute script 'my_script' due to unhandled exception!
```

Any Idea how to prenvent this.

Comment: You might have to specify hidden imports/datas/binaries for the pyinstaller. Have a look at https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html

Comment: Actually the path to the specified DLL exists, Pyinstaller did the build with torch module.